# Unable to create a child directory where parent directory has permission 774

Tags: php, file-permissions

*Amazon EC2, UBUNTU, APACHE server*

I used the following PHP code to create a directory in /gallery/ -

```
if (!file_exists("./gallery/$id")) 
    {
        mkdir("./gallery/$id", 0744, true);
        chown("./gallery/$id",get_current_user());
    }
```

The permission I set for /gallery/ is 774. The above code does not create any sub directory inside gallery.

However, setting the permission to 777 creates sub directory but the owner and group changes to 'www-data www-data' - I was expecting to see 'ubuntu ubuntu' as get_current_user() outputs 'ubuntu'

Can anyone please advise? I need to create sub directories in Gallery but I do not want to set Gallery's permission to 777.

Thank you.

Comment: `get_current_user()` returns the owner of the script, not the process owner. Apache is by default run with the `www-data`-user on Ubuntu. Try and set the owner and group of the `/gallery`-folder to `www-data` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Who is the owner, and what group is the owner of /gallery/ ?
744 for folder means it is traversable, readable and writable *for the owner*, 774 is the same *for the group*

If you chown /gallery/ to www-data it will work with permissions 744
As someone mentioned in the comments, the owner is www-data, because it's the owner of the process that runs the script.

If you want your directories to be owned by user ubuntu, you will have do add ubuntu to the www-data group. In this case only 774 will work.